# NFC и браузер на Android

Tags: android, url, браузер, nfc

Добрый день. Стоит задача при прикосновении смартфона к NFC метки, открыть браузер с определенной ссылкой. Как это можно сделать в Android. Документацию по теме не нашел по этому решил обратится к здешним гуру. Буду благодарен любой информации по теме !!!

Comment: Документация по [теме NFC](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/index.html). Документация по [теме открытия браузера](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common.html#ViewUrl). Это сложно не найти, если конечно, действительно искать.

Answer (score 1):

Все просто - нужно установить приложение    [NFC Tools](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.wakdev.wdnfc) и через него записать тег со ссылкой. Если  необходимо  разработать код записи такого тега из приложения - тоже могу пояснить